# WP8 - grid follow finger position

Tags: button, windows-phone-8, controls

I have custom user control, and I have a grid, and a button in it.

**This is what I want:**

When I hold down the button, the whole grid follow the fingers Y position.
So the whole user control follow the finger vertically.
*I dont know if the button is necessary.*

How can I do this?

**XAML**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}"> 
  <Button Content="" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
          Height="30" Visibility="Collapsed" Hold="Button_Hold"/> 
</Grid>
```

Comment: Please, post your code.

Comment: The XAML:

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{StaticResource PhoneChromeBrush}">
<Button Content="" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="30" Visibility="Collapsed" Hold="Button_Hold"/>
</Grid>

Comment: Post your C# or VB code also.

Comment: public partial class MenuBar : UserControl
{
   public MenuBar()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
   }
}